# ElasticSearch fetch child from parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all child with value "sales" at some field from parent with some unique id. 
this is my query:

```
GET /_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "query_string": {
                "query": "sales"
            }
        },
        {
            "has_parent": {
                "type": "role_permission_parent",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                            "resourceURI": "urn:module:com.qad.collaboration"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
},
"size": 100
}
```

I get a childs from different parents but not from only what I type. Why? And how I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `must` condition instead of `should`:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "sales"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "has_parent": {
                        "type": "role_permission_parent",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "resourceURI": "urn:module:com.qad.collaboration"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 100
}
```

Otherwise it works like "parent match" or "query_string match" instead of "parent match" and "query_string match"